# Changetab function works for IE and chrome but not FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Fore some reason, the current coding is being used on my ebay account and it works perfectly for on chrome and EI but not on firefox.

ebay has some limitation on the type of coding that can be used.

The coding is shown below with css and all.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE></TITLE>
    <STYLE>
    #maincontent {
        width: 860px;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        border-top-color: #CCC;
        border-right-color: #CCC;
        border-bottom-color: #CCC;
        border-left-color: #CCC;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    #tabContents {
        vertical-align: top;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        border-right-width: thin;
        border-bottom-width: thin;
        border-left-width: thin;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-top-color: #336633;
        border-right-color: #336633;
        border-bottom-color: #336633;
        border-left-color: #336633;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #21A54F;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #TabHidden {
        position: absolute;
        width: 834px;
        left: 57px;
        top: 277px;
        height: 260px;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #redirect {
        width: 746px;
        margin-left: 56px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #276B3F;
        font-size: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #TabDivPic {
        height: auto;
        width: 175px;
        margin-right: 30px;
        float: left;
    }
    .conts  {
        visibility:hidden
    }
    .tab    {
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size:10pt;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:normal;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #21A54F;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-right-width: thin;
        border-left-width: thin;
        border-right-color: #CCC;
        border-left-color: #CCC;
    }
    .selTab {
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #276B3F;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    #tabstyle #td {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    #tabtable {
        width: 656px;
    }
    </STYLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    //a public function that the container uses to pass in values for the labels
    function public_Labels(label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7){

        t1.innerText = label1;
        t2.innerText = label2;
        t3.innerText = label3;
        t4.innerText = label4;
        t5.innerText = label5;
        t6.innerText = label6;
        t7.innerText = label7;
    }

    //a public function that the container uses to pass in values for the card containers
    function public_Contents(contents1, contents2, contents3, contents4, contents5, contents6, contents7){

        t1Contents.innerHTML = contents1;
        t2Contents.innerHTML = contents2;
        t3Contents.innerHTML = contents3;
        t4Contents.innerHTML = contents4;
        t5Contents.innerHTML = contents5;
        t6Contents.innerHTML = contents6;
        t7Contents.innerHTML = contents7;

        init();
    }

    //sets the default display to tab 1
    function init(){
        tabContents.innerHTML = t1Contents.innerHTML;
    }   

    //this is the tab switching function
    var currentTab;
    var tabBase;
    var firstFlag = true;


    function changeTabs(event){

        if(firstFlag == true){
            currentTab = t1;
            tabBase = t1base;
            firstFlag = false;
        }

        if(window.event.srcElement.className == "tab"){

            currentTab.className = "tab";

            tabBase.style.backgroundColor = "white";

            currentTab = window.event.srcElement;

            tabBaseID = currentTab.id + "base";

            tabContentID = currentTab.id + "Contents";

            tabBase = document.all(tabBaseID);

            tabContent = document.all(tabContentID);

            currentTab.className = "selTab";

            tabBase.style.backgroundColor = "";

            tabContents.innerHTML = tabContent.innerHTML;

        }
    }

    </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <div id="maincontent">
    <DIV STYLE="position:relative; top:0px; height:400; width:746px; left:56px; border:none thin gray" onClick="changeTabs(event)" onload="init()">
    <TABLE id="tabtable" CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0>
        <TR id="tabstyle">
            <TD ID=t1 CLASS=selTab HEIGHT=25>TAB ONE</TD>
            <TD ID=t2 CLASS=tab>TAB TWO</TD>
            <TD ID=t3 CLASS=tab>TAB THREE</TD>
            <TD ID=t4 CLASS=tab>TAB FOUR</TD>
            <TD ID=t5 CLASS=tab>TAB FIVE</TD>
            <TD ID=t6 CLASS=tab>TAB SIX</TD>
            <TD ID=t7 CLASS=tab>TAB SEVEN</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD ID=t1base STYLE="height:2; border-left:solid thin white"></TD>
            <TD ID=t2base STYLE="height:2; background-color:white"></TD>
            <TD ID=t3base STYLE="height:2; background-color:white"></TD>
            <TD ID=t4base STYLE="height:2; background-color:white"></TD>
            <TD ID=t5base STYLE="height:2; background-color:white"></TD>
            <TD ID=t6base STYLE="height:2; background-color:white"></TD>
            <TD ID=t7base STYLE="height:2; background-color:white; border-right:solid thin white"></TD> 
        </TR>


        <TR>
            <TD HEIGHT="*" COLSPAN=7 ID=tabContents>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>

    </TD>

        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    </DIV>
      <div id="TabHidden">
      <DIV CLASS=conts ID=t1Contents>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
      </DIV>

      <DIV CLASS=conts ID=t2Contents>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
      </DIV>

      <DIV CLASS=conts ID=t3Contents>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
      </DIV>

      <DIV CLASS=conts ID=t4Contents>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
      </DIV>

      <DIV CLASS=conts ID=t5Contents>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
      </DIV>

      <DIV CLASS=conts ID=t6Contents>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
      </DIV>

      <DIV CLASS=conts ID=t7Contents>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
            content<br>
      </DIV>
    </div>
    </DIV>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

sorry for the mess. This is really my first time on this site and doing this type of coding.

Comment: You're doing several things that target IE. First, using `window.event` is IE-specific. You have an `event` parameter (which other browsers use), so you need to consider that too. Also, you are using `document.all` (IE-specific). Just use `document.getElementById` instead. Another thing is `event.srcElement`. Non-IE uses `event.target`. So you can't use one or the other for these - you have to normalize the options into one variable. It seems like Chrome has implemented some of these for the sake of supporting non-standard things

Comment: "supporting non-standard things" = web programming. :)